# How to remove the special characters in the columns and convert the columns into float?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to remove the last characters in the column and convert the column into float. The column type is object.

```
13.3\T

9.4\J

24.09006465036784\C

24.4140625\B

35.73069852941176\M
```

I tried to use the `df[column] = df[column].str[:5]` but not successful.

```
df['column'] = df['column'].str[:4]

df['column'].astype(float)
```

it's not dropping the last characters.
Getting error. Unable to convert the string into float

Comment: Please use your tags more judiciously. 3 of the 4 tags here were irrelevant; I've removed them and replaced them with [pandas], which is really what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get `floats` or `integers`, then cast by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) and last round by [`Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html):

```
df['column'] = (df['column'].str.extract(r'(\d+\.\d+|\d+)', expand=False)
                            .astype(float)
                            .round(2))
print (df)
   column
0   13.30
1    9.40
2   24.09
3   24.41
4   35.73
```

If always only floats:

```
df['column'] = df['column'].str.extract(r'(\d+\.\d+)', expand=False).astype(float).round(2)
print (df)
   column
0   13.30
1    9.40
2   24.09
3   24.41
4   35.73
```

EDIT:

```
def my_round(x): 
    x = x.str.extract(r'(\d+\.\d+)', expand=False) 
    x = x.astype(float).round(2) 
    return(x) 

df.iloc[:, 61:64] = df.iloc[:, 61:64].astype(str).apply(my_round)
```

Another idea is convert only object non numeric columns:

```
cols = df.iloc[:, 61:64].select_dtypes(object).columns
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(my_round)
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael. It works. Could you please explain the meaning of (\d+\. \d+)?

Comment: @Jason - it is regex for number `\d+` - one or more digits, then `.` and last number - one or more digits

Comment: Sure Jezrael. I have one more doubt. If I want to clean the three columns and I am passing function. And it's coming error. def round(x):
    x = x.str.extract(r'(\d+\.\d+)', expand=False)
    x = x.astype(float)
    return(x)

df.iloc[:, 61:64] = df.iloc[:, 61:64].apply(round)   AttributeError: ('Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas', 'occurred at index median_teriary_loan_as_perc_of_med_inc_AHC')

Comment: @Jason - quick fix is `df.iloc[:, 61:64] = df.iloc[:, 61:64].astype(str).apply(round)`

Comment: @jezrael  In the function I am converting into float. But when running the main again we are using casting into str (astype(str))??? it means convert again into string?

Comment: @Jason - Yes, it is quick fix, best use if possible mixed data in column - numeric with strings. Also added another solution for seelct only strings (object) columns and apply solution for it.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. My final question If I want to round the decimals into two  x = x.apply(lambda x: round (x,2)) ( I used this in the function but it's coming error) any suggestion from your side.

Comment: @Jason - use `x = x.astype(float).round(2)`

Comment: Please don't leave comments attempting to persuade other users into accepting an answer. Accepting an answer is completely optional, and left up to the asker's discretion. Comments like this can be perceived as bullying, and are otherwise completely off-topic.

Comment: @CodyGray - My idea is mainly teach OP if have no idea about it, I add this kind of commnet only for new users if not accepting no answers. Or is another way do it better?

Comment: There's no need to leave comments like this at all.

Comment: @CodyGray - Yes, but if my idea is teach new user about this possibility ?

Comment: The site already provides help, along with suggestions to accept an answer, in various places. You do not need to teach people about this.

Comment: @CodyGray - hmmm, meta consensus says it is OK to recommend once: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/asking-for-someone-to-accept-your-answer), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat), and more on MSO, so it is your personal opinion?

Comment: No, it's not my personal opinion. I count a *very* large volume of comments related to accepting answers in your recent history. That's a serious problem. I recommend that you stop leaving these comments entirely.

Comment: @CodyGray - hmmm, I try reduce it to minimum.

Comment: @jezrael I have one more doubt. Can you help me?

Comment: @Jason - sure, can you explain more?

Comment: Thanks @jezrael .. I have 10 columns which have characters again. Need to clean the same. values in the column B15.5, e10.5, 19.5K, NAN, Q2.4, NAN, T82.7, 14.5, 14.6P                --- I would like to remove the character. e10.5 - I want to remove the e. 14.6P -here i want to remove the P. can you suggest?

Comment: @ Jezrael -- No your solution works. but this one is a new problem. I need to remove first and last character in the column which I don't know the way.. Please suggest

Comment: @Jason - so how working `x = x.str[1:-1].astype(float).round(2)` ?

Comment: @Jezrael def removeFirstLastChar(x):
    x = x.str[1:-1].astype(float).round(2)
    return(x)

temp['column'] = temp['column'].apply(removeFirstLastChar) Getting error message "'str' object has no attribute 'str'"

Comment: @Jason - Use `temp[['column']] = temp[['column']].apply(removeFirstLastChar)`

Comment: @jezrael... I changed and used the above code and getting this error message  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self[k1] = value[k2]

Comment: AttributeError: ('Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas', 'occurred at index depression_adult')  --- This is the error message @jezrael

Comment: it means there ais numeric columns, use same solution like `.astype(str).apply(removeFirstLastChar)` or solution below by `select_dtypes(object)`

Comment: Because problem is need process strings values only by indexing `.str[1:-1]`

Comment: @jezrael... it works now. however, the problem is I have some numeric value in the column example 14.5, 25.6.. so this code removes the numeric value of first and last number.. I don't want to change the numeric value.. only thing to remove alphabets.. i'm breaking my head for the last three hours.. appreciate your hep and solution

Comment: @Jason - Is possible create new question? With sample data and expected output?

Comment: @jezrael -- Hi, could you please assit me for this problem I have 10 columns (dtype: datetime64). I want to remove the date and month from the columns and keep only the year.

10-01-1880 --> Would like to remove day and month

expecting --> 1880

Comment: @Jason - Use `df = df.apply(lambda x: x.dt.year)`

Comment: @jezrael I used df['year'] = df['year'].apply(lambda x: x.dt.year) ..It's coming error ""
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'dt'""

Comment: @Jason - Can you create new question with sample data and expected output?

Comment: @Jason - Use `df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'], errors='coerce').dt.year`

Comment: @Jason - and if need this for 10 columns `df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, errors='coerce').dt.year)`

Comment: @jezrael  -- it works without errors='coerce'.. what is mean by coerce?

Comment: @Jason it is only if not parseable value like `a` it convert to `NaT`. So working `df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).dt.year)` ? Or only one column?

Comment: @jezrael -- It works now.. I used df['column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column']).dt.year

Comment: @jezrael -- I have some doubt in coding which you taught me last time. Is it possible to come in private chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191424/discussion-between-jezrael-and-jason).

Comment: @jezrael u there

Comment: @jezrael u there

Comment: @Jason - yes, I am here

Comment: @jezrael can you come to private chat?

Comment: @jezrael Hi Are you online today? I need your help.

Comment: @Jason - Ya, I am online

Comment: @jezrael I have a serious doubt and unable to post the result here. Can I send you email my problem? This is regarding nested json objects. I want to comvert into pandas dataframe. Downloaded data from WEB API

Comment: @Jason - Ya, you can send me email, but not 100% sure, if possible help, because nested json are not easy.

Comment: ok. Can I have your email? This is my original post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56220983/how-to-convert-json-object-into-python-dataframe

Comment: jozefeg@gmail.com - Is this your email?

Comment: exactly, also please remove comment for not parse by bots

Comment: @jezrael I sent email. Please advise

Comment: @jezrael Hi Are you online today? Need your help again

Comment: @Jason - I am online. ;)

Comment: @jezrael can we discuss in chat?

Comment: @jezrael sorry I cant find the link. You have to send a link..sorry

Comment: [link](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191424/discussion-between-jezrael-and-jason)

Comment: @jezrael.. link is not working.. its says room has automatically frozen

Comment: This room has been automatically frozen for inactivity --

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194090/discussion-between-jezrael-and-jason).

Comment: @jezrael u there

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to drop the last 2 characters and convert to float:

```
df[column] = df[column].str[:-2].astype(float)
```

You can also use the following approach:

```
df[column] = pd.to_numeric(df[column].str[:-2])
```

You can then use the following to round your data to 2 decimal places:

```
df = df.round(2)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
0  13.30
1   9.40
2  24.09
3  24.41
4  35.73
```